# Publish a Git repo to a wiki from project repo

Tags: c++, git, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

In the following link, there's documentation of how to publish git repo to Azure wiki.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

I have a project written in c++ / c.
It is in Azure repo.
I'm trying to understand how to create wiki pages to document the code with links to a specific location in the code - function let's say. What happens when the repo changes? or the function changes? the wiki doesn't update the link.
I understand that the wiki repo publish will fix it. Since it is git based.

When I do it, the files are empty, as I understand it - it is because only md files are read by azure.

But I have over 100 files of cpp, and creating an md for each one will be very messy and will cloud my project heavily.
Is there a way to do it without the conversion mess?
Or in a way to not cloud my project with so many files?
While also being consistent with changes.

I don't understand why this is even required.
I have a git project in Azure, and then I need to swap it to md which is basically text files to publish them back into git, this seems unneeded.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why are you not busy reading Azure documentation rather than asking here???

Comment: I am, very much so, in fact everything I find assume I am using md files.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you want to do. You want to store markdown documentation **within** code files?

Comment: Usually with documentation generators, you just regenerate after changing your code. I assume you could do the same with this tool, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: I am trying to avoid creating more files. I am not sure if the following is possible: Publish the current git repo that is in my project without converting it with some documentation generator @DanielMann

Comment: You're still not really explaining the problem clearly. Provide examples of what the files in question that you'd like to publish as a wiki look like.

Comment: I have a main.cpp and a.cpp. I pushed both of them into a project into azure git repo. They are both in a respective file with the same name. When I publish under wiki git code it only sees the folder main and a and not the files in them main.cpp and a.pp. I want to do this so that when I link a code line from wiki documentation to wiki code it will save the location even if changes were made (git solves that). I learned that I need to have a file called main.md and a.md which will create 4 files, in a project iwth over 100 files this seem too much... not sure how to avoid that.